# jsPDF - I need help embedding a pdf onto a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to create a pdf that will be displayed on a web page but I can't seem to get it to embed correctly. The pdf does load if I put in `doc.output('dataurl');` but it loads in a new window (I know that is what it's supposed to do). I made a div that uses object tags to hold the pdf and it does load a pdf file but it wont the load the jsPDF. What I'm trying to do is make an embedded pdf like the one on their main page, https://parall.ax/products/jspdf. What code would I need to add in order to get it to load in the object tags? It has to be possible since they have a working version.

p.s. I'm using JQuery if there is a quick shortcut in there.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Ok new problem. So I added this: $('#ID').attr("src", doc.output("dataurlstring")); It works but it makes a new problem. It doesn't always load. Sometimes it loads just fine, other times it will load the div but not the iframe or content. There aren't any errors and all my console.log() lines run. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a copy of the jspdf code locally our referencing it remotely?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for that page? Most browsers allow you to view the source code for the page you are looking at.

Comment: I have a copy of jsPDF locally included in my project. I've looked at their website but I can't find the exact code that allows for the embedding.

Comment: Can't you just use `<iframe src="foo.url"></iframe>`? It works flawlessly on all modern browsers, and is really easy and light to implement.

Comment: I'm still kind of new to javascript and html. How should I add it? I have:
`var data = doc.output("dataurlstring");
$('ID').src('#{data}');`

Is this right? It doesn't seem to work. 

my template looks like:
`<div>
    <iframe id="ID"></iframe>
</div>`