# How to embed in html page a PDF generated on the fly with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I had project with java that created the pdf from the back-end and saved that pdf for while so the user could download that file within a frame of time, so embedding or sending that file was easy because it have a physical copy in the server, now for this project the pdf is generated with the dynamic html content the user chooses with jsPDF, but this file the user only can save it directly to his/her computer.

There is a way to show this pdf generated on the fly embeded in a html page like a modal/div or a tooltip (for a thumbnail preview)?

It would be better if there is mobile friendly solution.

Since mobiles have some issues with iframe i'm not considering that as an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPDF - I need help embedding a pdf onto a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353192/jspdf-i-need-help-embedding-a-pdf-onto-a-web-page)